# Dynamically adding new fabric canvases

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am working on a project that requires creating multiple canvas elements (separate bars each representing one distinct gradient). I would like to do this dynamically with fabric.js, eg:

```
 function add_gradient(color_stops){
     // Add a new rectangular canvas with fill representing specified gradient
     var grad_box = document.getElementById("divWithCanvases");

     var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
     grad_box.appendChild(newCanvas);

     var gradCanvas = fabric.Canvas(newCanvas, {width: 500, height:50});
     var ctx = gradCanvas.getContext('2d');
     // Do stuff to canvas...
 }
```

However, the call to `fabric.Canvas` fails with an error "this.initialize is undefined". (fabric.js line 1627, version 1.4.13)

How can I either:

1. Generate a new fabric canvas based on an HTML element (instead of the string id), or,
2. Append an auto-generated new canvas element to the DOM? (the form fabric.Canvas() without arguments will make... something... but it can't be used with `appendChild`)

According to the [fabric.js documentation](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#initialize), the `fabric.Canvas` constructor accepts either an HTMLElement, or a string element id. I can only make it work with the string.

Comment: how to create multiple canvases with stringified canvas data ? I have an array of stringified canvases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function [fabric.Canvas](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html) is a constructor, you have to call it with the [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

```
var gradCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(newCanvas, {width: 500, height:50});
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. Confirmed that it works, and a fabric canvas can be created from an element using this syntax.

Comment: @abought can a fabric canvas be created by supplying a preexisting STRINGIFIED or  PARSED canvas ?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the above error because of `<div id="canvas"> </div>`

Make sure your html element should be canvas

```
<canvas id="canvas"> </canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

**When we want to add canvas dynamically and want to call canvas fabric API then we need to give a different name like this..**

```
var html_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

html_canvas.id = "CursorLayer";

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas(html_canvas, canvasConfigOptions);
// canvasConfigOptions is optional
```

Now we can perform all fabric operations on this **`canvas`**

Answer (score 0):

You can create canvas element from the fabric utility itself via `createCanvasElement` and then assign this newly created elemment as first parameter of Canvas constructor function to create virtual canvas and still have the ability to perform operations.

```
let tempCanvasEl =  fabric.util.createCanvasElement(),
tempCanvasCtx = tempCanvasEl.getContext('2d',{ willReadFrequently: true }),
tempCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(tempCanvasEl)
```

or even use `staticCanvas` constructor in case if the new canvas is only for read operations like getPixelColor for example as `willReadFrequently` is true here.

`tempCanvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas(tempCanvasEl)`

Hope this helps.